# Event Listeners is empty

Tags: javascript, dom-events, internet-explorer-11

I have problem that my Internet Explorer 11.0.9600 Not showing any Events to any type.

I ran into a problem while using IE 11.0.9600, I was trying to visualize the list of Events associated with a specific tag, but (as shown in the picture) such events are not reported in the dev tools.

[image]

While using Chrome I can see all the Events as shown in the picture below:

[image]

The code snippet is the same and I am focusing the same tag, is there any reason why this is happening ? Is it something I am doing wrong or is it a browser related issue ?